# A strategy ITC Baskerville font for vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-design

With Adobe Illustrator to create my several pictures I'm using the fonts **ITC New Baskerville Std** or **ITC New Baskerville** with options roman and italic.

**I ask you if exists the option bold**.

[image]

Does anyone know if exist the same type of font that generates or the vector symbol (as in the figure) or the horizontal dash above the character (green rectangle)? Or an alternative automatic procedure to generate the arrow or without arrow?

The rectangles in red and green with the font inside and the horizontal dash were created by himself. The picture is into a common american Physics books. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: I don't know that you'll find a *font* with those types of diacritic symbols. You would most likely need to *manually* create the diacritics in conjunction with a standard typeface.

Comment: @Scott I'm not 100% sure but I think those vector symbols exist. Put a dash when the carriers are many and always put them in the same alignment is too difficult for me for reasons of time.

Comment: They may exist. I can merely state that I've never seen a font with arrow diacritics. I know there are fonts with arrows, but not as diacritics. And the line above the *b* appears much longer and thinner than I customarily see. Again, I could be wrong. That would not surprise me.

Comment: a late addition: You surely also need vector formulas. Complex ones (=more than an addition) need some equation editor. The same name symbols and math expressions, too can be used in illustrations, if you export them as images.

Comment: @user287001 Can you add another answer please?

Comment: I have not much more to say, but you get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build each character "manually" you always can create a Symbol at the Symbol Window and drag and drop to the page every time you need to place it. The symbols are editable, if you change something all the symbols on the file will be replaced.

[image: symbol]

Comment: I have understood your answer. But I haven't peraphs your palette with my AI 2018.

Comment: Menu Window > Symbols

Answer (score 1):

Clicking twice two times (double click and double click) on the character indicated on the Gliphs window picture, using Baskerville font, the line is automatically placed on top of the previous character:

[image: line]

For the b and arrow, i just think about a Baskerville "b" followed by a Wingdins 3 arrow and a character style for each. It would be easier on Indesign with just a grep style.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't Entire Font. Using Baskerville font, into the glyphs I haven't the overline. I have difficult to solve myself. Is there an alternative font that it have overline?

Comment: I guess Baskerville is a system font on Mac, which system are you working with?

Comment: OS W7. Into the panel glyphs I have "Mostra: font intero" or "Alternative per la selezione attuale" and below my ITC New Baskerville.

Comment: Ok, is not ITC New Baskerville (228 characters), this is a short version font, is just Baskerville as in the picture from the answer (1.846 characters).

Comment: Where is in internet free font Baskerville (1.846 characters)? I have not found.

Comment: Baskerville free???? I don't know, as i told you is a system font on Mac OS X, the one 
 i use for the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS

Comment: Now I vote your answer. +1. But I have searched and to have Baskervill font you must pay it.

Answer (score 1):

A late addition:

No need to find such font version altough you can easily build one in a font editor. Nobody else has it and you will easily cause a nasty disorder, if you happen to use it as font in a distributed writing.

If you have vectors, you surely need also math formulas with them. Complex formulas (more than a sum or difference) need some equation editor. You can export as images from the equation editor as well separate vector name symbols as full expressions and use them in your illustrations.

Comment: I use always LaTeX and never equation editor. See my profile :-). +1

Comment: LaTeX is an advanced version of the concept, a description language, one which gives full typographic control.  I guess you cannot construct in iIllustrator anything resembling, no matter do you have the needed math fonts. I guess if you open a LaTeX based PDF in Illustrator, the result isn't a perfect formula. (here I can well guess wrong). But  you can outline all fonts in PDF and after it open that PDF in Illustrator. The images should be then exact.